# How can I create a team watchlist in Azure DevOps, similar to how individuals can follow items?

Tags: query, dashboard, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, I'm trying to create a "team watchlist" that allows visibility for the entire team to see followed items on the dashboard.

For example, queries can be filtered by ID=@follows and the dashboard will show items followed by the signed in user, but is there a way to do this by team?

*OR* can a query be done in the dashboard that shows a specific person's follows if a team project owner follows items?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No. You may use tags as a workaround. Add a new tag and create a query for it. Then you may add this query to a dashboard and check it periodically.

[image]